# Naming the return type of a generic function

Tags: typescript, generics, decorator, es6-class

To not fall victim to the XY problem, here's what I want to accomplish: I have a generic decorator creator function that returns a generic decorator function (or ES6 mixin) (like `<T1, T2>(...args) => <T3>(base) => class extends base { ... };` and I want to name the type of the result depending on the generic parameters.
This is so I can restrict other generic parameters (in other functions) to have been passed through that decorator at least once.

I eagerly waited for TS 2.8 and thought `ReturnType` would solve my problem, but I failed to be able to properly use it for this case. Naively I simply tried using `ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof myMixin>>`, but this doesn't work as all type parameters of `myMixin` are coerced to `{}`.

The following (simpler) example illustrates the problem:

```js
type ClassConstructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

const mixin = <B extends ClassConstructor<HTMLElement>, T>(base: B, arg: T) => {
    return class extends base {
        prop: T = arg;
    };
};

const Test1 = mixin(HTMLElement, 10); // using inference
type Test1Prop = typeof (new Test1()).prop; // number

type MixinReturnType = ReturnType<typeof mixin>;
const Test2: MixinReturnType = mixin(HTMLElement, 10); // using explicit type annotation
type Test2Prop = typeof (new Test2()).prop; // {}
```

TypeScript inference correctly names the type of the instance property. As soon as I give it a name, however, it turns to garbage. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on what's going on.  If you explicitly annotate the type of a variable with a wider type than its value, the compiler (usually*) forgets the narrower type of the value and treats the variable as the wider type only.  For example:

```
interface General {
  foo: string;
}
interface Specific extends General {
  bar: number
}
declare function getSpecific(): Specific;
declare function acceptSpecific(x: Specific): void;

const implicitlyTyped = getSpecific();
acceptSpecific(implicitlyTyped); // okay

const explicitlyTyped: General = getSpecific();
acceptSpecific(explicitlyTyped); // error!
```

The `explicitlyTyped` variable is only understood by the compiler to be of type `General`, and so it is an error to call `acceptSpecific(explicitlyTyped)`.  This is responsible for the problem where the widened `MixinReturnType` causes all subsequent inspections of `Test2` to disappoint you.

Therefore the solution cannot be to find a version of `MixinReturnType` that is somehow generic/wide enough to accept all outputs of `mixin()` but narrow enough to preserve the exact type of each specific output of `mixin()`.  No such type exists:

```
const Test2: MixinReturnType = mixin(HTMLElement, 10); 
const t2Prop = new Test2().prop;

const Test3: MixinReturnType = mixin(HTMLElement, "hey");
const t3Prop = new Test3().prop;
```

You want `Test3` to be the same type as `Test2` but you want `t3Prop` to be a different type from `t2Prop`, which just doesn't work.

<sub>*[Control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) will sometimes narrow a variable to string/number/boolean literals or single constituents of a union, but that is not applicable here.</sub>

---

Here's something that might work (depending on what you're trying to do).  Use a generic helper function that just passes the input through to the output, but  requires the input to be assignable to `MixinReturnType`, like this:

```
const requireMixinReturnType = <M extends MixinReturnType>(m: M) => m;
```

Note that this function is generic in `M`; so if `M` is narrower than `MixinReturnType`, the output will also be narrower.  Let's see it in action:

```
const Test2 = requireMixinReturnType(mixin(HTMLElement, 10));         
const t2Prop = new Test2().prop; // number
```

This is good, in that `t2Prop` is now known to be `number`.  You might wonder how this is any better than the implicitly typed `Test1`.  Well, it isn't really; after all, there's not really much point in writing `requireMixinReturnType(mixin(...))`.  But now you do have a way to prevent someone form passing you a bad mixin type without widening the input:

```
const BadMixin = requireMixinReturnType(HTMLElement); // error!
// Property 'prop' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'.
```

So probably you wouldn't use `requireMixinReturnType()` unless you're trying to catch a bad type early.

---

More likely, you would take the function you care about that currently accepts a `MixinReturnType` and make it generic:

```
declare function doConcrete(m: MixinReturnType): void {
   const p = new m().prop; // {}, oops
}

declare function doGeneric<M extends MixinReturnType>(m: M): void {
       const p = new m().prop; // still {}, oops
}
```

Uh oh, TypeScript is not smart enough to take the generic `M` and extract the type of `prop`.  There are some ways to deal with this.  The most straightforward is to forget about `MixinReturnType` and instead think about the generic definition we care about.  Something like this:

```
function doGeneric<T, E extends HTMLElement>(
  m: ClassConstructor<E & { prop: T }>
): void {
  const p = new m().prop; // T, that's good
}
```

In this case, we're saying that the `m` parameter must be a constructor that returns something of type `E & {prop: T}`, where `E` is something assignable to `HTMLElement` and `T` is anything.  Now the compiler realizes that `p` is of type `T`.  Let's try it out with something that returns something, like:

```
function getProp<T, E extends HTMLElement>(
  m: ClassConstructor<E & { prop: T }>
): T {
  return new m().prop; // type checks, yay!
}

const t2Prop = getProp(Test2); // number, yay!
```

That works!  This was very long-winded; hope it makes sense and is of some help.  Good luck!

Comment: > You want Test3 to be the same type as Test2 but you want t3Prop to be a different type from t2Prop, which just doesn't work.

If we could somehow make the type generic, as in `MixinReturnType<HTMLElement, number>` this would work.

Comment: You can define it as `type MixinReturnType<E extends HTMLElement, T> =  ClassConstructor<E & { prop: T }>`, but `MixinReturnType` by itself is not a concrete type anymore and cannot be the annotated type of a variable.

Comment: While this approach works, its not as nice as being able to infer the return type based on the arguments, since you'll basically have to declare the class twice, and you also cannot reason about static members that way.

Comment: I don't see static members in your code.  You don't have to use `ClassConstuctor<>`; you can make it your own type with every static member you care about.  Declaring the class twice: I can't think of a way around that.  If someone has a better suggestion I'd love to see it.

Comment: Yes, my examples didn't contain any. I am using the decorator for web components, so most instances have something like `static get observedAttributes(): string[]`. 

Anyway, I've had troubles with TS telling me `type MixinReturnType<E extends HTMLElement, T> = ClassConstructor<E & { prop: T }>` this isn't a constructor function anymore, when using it in the mixin, but I have worked around that now. Thanks for all the help!